# Portlet application/pdf is not a supported mime type error

Tags: pdf, jsf, primefaces, portlet, portletbridge

I am facing this error - "application/pdf" is not a supported mime type. I am trying to save the content of p:editor as pdf to my local machine.

Imports

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

Function

```
        public StreamedContent getFile() {
                try {
                     ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                     Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
                     PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, os);
                     document.open();
                     document.addCreationDate();
                    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
                     String str = "<html><head></head><body>"+ this.getMessage() +"</body></html>";
                     htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
                     document.close();

                     InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

                     file = new DefaultStreamedContent(is, "application/pdf", "ohyeah.pdf");
                     return file;
                  }
                  catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
                  }
            }
```

Following an excellent post at : https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=21342&p=170835#p170835

Please help !

EDIT------------------

If i use mime type as image/jpg, then also I receive the same error. Issue looks like something else. Can anyone point it to me please .

```
javax.portlet.faces.BridgeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image/jpg is not a supported mime type
```

Comment: This question needs a [MCVE]. What PrimeFaces components are you using in your view? What PrimeFaces version are you using? What Liferay Faces version(s) are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Melloware for pointing it out that the error is portlet related.

If anyone is facing the same issue, here is the solution which worked for me. Tweak it as per your needs.

```
public StreamedContent getFile() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        final PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();
        final HttpServletResponse res = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);
        res.setContentType("application/pdf");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        //res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\".pdf\"");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+subject+".pdf");
        res.setHeader("Refresh", "1");
        res.flushBuffer();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream out=res.getOutputStream();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        document.open();
        document.addCreationDate();
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
        String str =this.getMessage();
        htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
        document.close();
        baos.writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a poor solution since you're returning `null` from this method. If you're going to take complete control of the response and not use any PrimeFaces functionality, why not use a custom `Resource` and `ResourceHandler` like in the [Liferay Faces Export PDF Portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces-bridge-impl/tree/4.1.2/demo/jsf-export-pdf-portlet/src/main/java/com/liferay/faces/demos/resource).